# Could we have a visual indicator of whether live updates are active?

Tags: feature-request, live-refresh

Sometimes, people get disconnected from the live update server. Bugs, flaky Internet connection, maintenance, it happens.

I find the live updates quite useful for keeping track of new posts, but sometimes I get disconnected and I won't have any idea it happened. Could be hours before I notice the lack of activity, because sometimes, there really isn't any.

Could we get a visual indicator that tells us whether live updates are active on the current page? Here's two ideas:

- a symbol in the header somewhere that changes depending on live connectivity
- showing `(?)` in the title bar if the connection was dropped (not if it failed initially, no point in having it on every tab if that particular server is down)

Answer (score 2):

This suggestion is good, but not trivial to implement. I'm using the given WebSocket feature to generate real-time desktop notifications, and also encountered the issue you've mentioned.

Although my application is slightly different (I want to make sure that the connection always exists, you want to show a notification when something happens), the techniques are similar.

Chrome supports the online / offline events. On online, I'm resetting the socket connection: [source code](https://github.com/Rob--W/stackexchange-notifications/blob/9949828f865faa305f15e4da8ef74160e047f301/Chrome/using-websocket.js#L95-L101).
Firefox's online/offline events are useless, because these only fire when the user manually selects the "Work offline" option in the menu...

---

**Alternative method**
Currently, the backend broadcasts a "hb" message every 5 minutes. This characteristic can be utilized by checking whether the connection is stable or not with `setInterval` ([source code](https://github.com/Rob--W/stackexchange-notifications/blob/9949828f865faa305f15e4da8ef74160e047f301/Chrome/using-websocket.js#L125-L154)).

1. `ws.onopen` event - Store `Date.now()` in a variable, say `lastHeartbeat`, and start watching the connection using `setInterval`.
   In the watcher, check if the difference between `Date.now()` and `lastHeartbeat` is exceeds a certain value (at least >300 because the heartbeat runs every ~ 5 minutes).
2. `ws.onmessage` event with message "hb" - Update `lastHeartbeat` with `Date.now()`

The disadvantage of the last method is that it's not known *immediately* whether or not the connection died. So, if you unplug your cable for a minute, and a message comes in during this minute, you won't get notified of it.

Comment: PS. If anyone knows a reliable method to detect network connection in Firefox, please share. It's going to be used in a Firefox add-on, so NPAPI plugins are also alright (provided that the source code / clear documentation is available). I think that I've found the relevant commit in Chromium's source code, but I don't know how to use it: https://bugs.webkit.org/attachment.cgi?id=161672&action=prettypatch

Comment: 5 minutes seems to be too long - I'd be interested to see how much bandwidth would be required to send a ping/pong every 30 seconds or so

Comment: @Swadq The high-level ping/pong interval of 5 minutes is already implemented. I'm not proposing any changes to the API, but rather providing some details about the implementation of the requested feature.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, please!

This would be very useful. Especially for users living in an area with terrible internet connectivity, where the connection gets lost all the time.

I use the live updates to observe my favorite tags on *Stack Overflow*  and it would be very useful to see if live updates are still delivered or not.