# Take action when WebSocket connection gets lost

Tags: feature-request, live-refresh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Could we have a visual indicator of whether live updates are active?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129274/could-we-have-a-visual-indicator-of-whether-live-updates-are-active)

#### My problem:

I love the [real time updates to questions, answers, and inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox) we have now, but there's a problem when the WebSocket connection gets lost.

Consider the following scenario:

1. Open any SE page with real time updates.
2. Have connection problems (e. g., dis- and reconnect to the Internet).
3. Posts, edits, reputation and inbox don't get updated anymore.

Unfortunately, as an inhabitant of a developing country, `2.` happens quite often to me. Since `3.` doesn't trigger any notification, I miss new posts and messages in the inbox. That makes me a sad panda.

#### My request:

I don't know if any of the following ideas is feasible or which would be easier to implement.

- Restore the WebSocket connection automatically if it got lost.
- Display a notification when the WebSocket connection gets lost. Something like:

  > Due to connection problems, the real time updates to questions, answers, and inbox have been suspended. <a href="javascript:location.reload(true)">Click here</a> to refresh the page.

The first would be my favorite, but I'd be happy with either one.

Comment: Non intrusive notification, please(like badges).. Chat has an obnoxious popup. Necessary, I guess, since chat absolutely requires a connection(though its annoying when I'm just reading through and it pops up tons of times). Also, the notification should kill itself if the connection comes back...

Comment: @lunboks: Same problem, slightly different suggestion. But close enough. Voting to close.